# Does a device need to be rooted in order for a background process to take screenshots

Tags: android

Can a process take screen shots without the device being rooted?

Answer (score 1):

On some devices you can grab the framebuffer without root, but these are not all that common compared to the number of Android devices in general.

In short, if you are aiming for a wide userbase, you will need to have the device rooted.